# NSDate becomes nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

NSDate becomes nil when I change device time to 24 hour format.

```
NSString *stampStr = @"10/6/2017 8:57:44 AM";
NSDateFormatter *oldFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[oldFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:10800]; // GMT+3
[oldFormatter setTimeZone:tz];
NSDate *oldDate = [oldFormatter dateFromString:stampStr];
```

But it works fine when change to 12 hr format in iPhone device.

Comment: You need to set the locale to POSIX.https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `locale` of your `NSDateFormatter`

```
oldFormater.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```